# Grouping users in SQL based on how often they appear in the database

Tags: sql

I am facing some issues in SQL. I have a table of users (user ids) who have bought in a store (purchase ids). To make it clearer, let’s say that I have a table with 2 columns:

```
Name_user Purchase_id
James   AAA
Mary BBB
Andrew   CCC
Mary DDD
Andrew   EEE
Andrew   FFF
John GGG
```

I know how to get:

```
Name_user  Number of purchases
James 1
Mary 2
Andrew 3
John 1
```

But I would like to get:

```
Number of purchases Number of Users
1 2 (James+john)
2 1 (Mary)
3 1 (Andrew)
Do you know how to do that?
```

I created this SQL fiddle in order to help me but I don't really know how to move forward: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7468c/1

Here is what I did:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT client) OVER (PARTITION BY purchase_id) =1 then '1 purchase'    
WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT client) OVER (PARTITION BY purchase_id) =2 then '2 purchases'    
ELSE 'Over 2' END,     
COUNT(client) 
FROM    the_unknown_table 
GROUP BY Purchase_id, Client
```

Thanks,

JP

Comment: What database are you really using?  Your question is tagged MySQL, but the sample code is not MySQL-compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT tt.cnt as num_of_purchases,count(*) as num_of_users
FROM(
    SELECT t.user,count(*) as cnt
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY t.user) tt
GROUP BY tt.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL with two levels of aggregation:

```
select numpurchases, count(*) as numusers,
       group_concat(user) as users
from (select user, count(*) as numpurchases
      from t
      group by user
     ) t
group by numpurchases
order by numpurchases;
```

If you don't need the names, then just do:

```
select numpurchases, count(*) as numusers
from (select user, count(*) as numpurchases
      from t
      group by user
     ) t
group by numpurchases
order by numpurchases;
```

I call this a "histogram-of-histogram" query and it should work in any database.

Comment: I think the (names example) was for us.